# Flutter sort Firebase snapshot by timestamp

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm trying to sort snapshot by timestamp but returns original order.
data structure looks like this 
[image]

I have two snapshot and timestamps are `-1536025466539` and `-1536025893015`.
So, I expect `-1536025893015` to come first after sorted.
Does anyone know how to sort correctly?

Code:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data?.snapshot?.value;
    map.values.toList().sort((a, b) {
      return a['timestamp'].compareTo(b['timestamp']);
    // also not work return b['timestamp'].compareTo(a['timestamp']);
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately when you call `snapshot.data?.snapshot?.value;` the resulting `Map` doesn't have space for the order of the items anymore. You will need to listen to `.childAdded` events to maintain the value of the items in Flutter, at least until this issue is addressed: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20745.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So, basically you can't iterate until it gets fixed right?

Comment: Correct. But you can listen to `.childAdded` to accomplish the same `onChildAdded`.

Answer (score 7):

From the above code, it looks like you are not having a `variable` to hold the list.

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = {
    "one": {"timestamp": 1},
    "two": {"timestamp": 2}
  };
  List list = map.values.toList(); //variable which holds new list created from Map.
                                   //As it new list, any change in list will not have no impact on map.
  list.sort((a, b) {
    return b["timestamp"].compareTo(a["timestamp"]);
  }); // inplace sort
  print(list); // [{timestamp: 2}, {timestamp: 1}]
```

If you want `key` also in the result,

```
 var list = map.entries.toList();
 list.sort((a, b) => b.value["timestamp"].compareTo(a.value["timestamp"]));
 var list2 = list.map((a) => {a.key: a.value}).toList();
 print(list2); // [{two: {timestamp: 2}}, {one: {timestamp: 1}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately when you call `snapshot.data?.snapshot?.value`, the resulting `Map` doesn't have space for the order of the items anymore.

In most Firebase SDKs you can solve this by looping over the children of the snapshot in the value event listener. But in Flutter you will need to listen to `onChildAdded` events to maintain the value of the items in Flutter, at least until this issue is addressed: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20745.

From one of my own projects:

```
ref.orderByKey().equalTo("child1").onChildAdded.listen((event) {
  print(event.snapshot.key);
});
ref.child("child1").once().then((snapshot) {
  print("Done loading all data for child1");
});
```

This will first print the keys of all child nodes (in the requested order), and then `"Done loading all data for child1"`.

Comment: Nope. Firebase deduplicates these listeners behind the scenes, so this is a common way to detect when complete (initial and increment) updates are done.