# Flutter: Items in StreamBuilder(Using firebase realtime database) are sorted randomly

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, stream-builder

I'm creating a simple application with Firebase Realtime database where a user inputs a text and it gets added to a list of chats.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('chats');
  TextEditingController _txtCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var comments = _firebaseRef.orderByChild('time').limitToLast(10);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: TextField(controller: _txtCtrl)),
                SizedBox(
                    width: 80,
                    child: OutlineButton(
                        child: Text("Add"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          sendMessage();
                        }))
              ])),
              StreamBuilder(
                stream: comments.onValue,
                builder: (context, snap) {
                  if (snap.hasData &&
                      !snap.hasError &&
                      snap.data.snapshot.value != null) {
                    Map data = snap.data.snapshot.value;
                    List item = [];

                    data.forEach(
                        (index, data) => item.add({"key": index, ...data}));

                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: item.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(item[index]['message']),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  } else
                    return Center(child: Text("No data"));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    _firebaseRef.push().set({
      "message": _txtCtrl.text,
      'time': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
    });
  }


}
```

It stores and retrieves data perfectly. But when I try adding data, the new items are placed at random points in the list.

For example, in the image below, the last item I placed into the list was 'Nine'. But it was put in the center of the list:

[image]

I've tried sorting the list by timestamps, but it did nothing.

What could be causing this issue? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the way you sort?

Comment: _firebaseRef.orderByChild('time').limitToLast(10);

Comment: What is the type of `time`, can i see a value sample?

Comment: add `print(snap.data.snapshot.value);` before `Map data = snap.data.snapshot.value;` and after clicking add tell us what do you get as output

Comment: based on each addition: time1 =1587847259193, time2 = 1587847282380

Comment: Replying to Peter Haddad: {-M5moC_vhcWU2E-DD5Aa: {message: eight, time: 1587842963835}, -M5mo-B4T2JGuFqBFQFC: {message: six, time: 1587842908933}, -M5n3GaXlOBIG3x55Zxy: {message: hello world, time: 1587847174562}, -M5mwHEO-mMH18efuVs5: {message: hello, time: 1587845080025}, -M5mpQIPys4GvKwjnUMU: {message: nine, time: 1587843282138}, -M5n3aFriRc0EmbWOINE: {message: one, time: 1587847259192}, -M5mnzImBoXwa2B9tc7S: {message: five, time: 1587842905331}, -M5n3fvB3TzUjHB_HG3Y: {message: one, time: 1587847282380}, -M5mo0BU6n04-16YIhag. :....

Comment: I just added an example of how to use `FirebaseList` to my answer that to the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `snap.data.snapshot.value;` the data in the snapshot (which **is** ordered) is converted to a `Map<String, Object>` which isn't ordered. To maintain the order, you'll want to listen to `onChild...` instead.

Note that FlutterFire has a convenient [`firebase_list` library](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_list/ui_firebase_list-library.html) that handles most of the heavy lifting of `onChild...` for you.

Also see:

- [Flutter Firebase Database wrong timestamp order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808719/flutter-firebase-database-wrong-timestamp-order/51811808#51811808)
- [Flutter sort Firebase snapshot by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52158037/flutter-sort-firebase-snapshot-by-timestamp/52158580#52158580)
- [Flutter: Firebase Real-Time database orderByChild has no impact on query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result/61333575#61333575)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

use a Query

```
Query comments = _firebaseRef.orderByChild('time').limitToLast(10);
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: ah damn. will search for it later when I'm free :). good luck man

Comment: @WilsonOWilson [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808719/flutter-firebase-database-wrong-timestamp-order)

Comment: When I try it, I get a list of maps that is perfectly arranged. But when I remove the onChildAdded() function, it does nothing. I guess the problem lies in my streambuilder

Comment: To resolve my problem, I may just use that method to create a list of my data and use a listview builder to do the rest

Comment: oh weird. Good luck m8.